# Sorting bug in Notion list view

Tags: notion

Why is Notion keeping messing up with my entries?
The fact that I didn't set any specific sorting rule doesn't mean, that I want to see my entries in a random order every time. That fact means that I want it to preserve my manual order.
How to fix this? Any hints? 
P.S.
Sorry, I'm not sure whether it's a proper place to ask Notion-related question. Where should I ask it instead?